# android studio edittext field value conversion

Tags: android, if-statement, android-edittext, try-catch

I have a fragment with a `EditText` and save button. when user click the save button, it should check whether the edittext value is out of range or the same data type. For this case, the value type should be "FLOAT" and range is "0.00 - 1000.00".

here's my code for the fragment.java.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_fragment,container, false);

    int field = getArguments().getInt("field");

    //Modify label
   // TextView fieldLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(field);
    //fieldLabel.setText(MainActivity.pageNames[field]);

    return v;


}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //---Button view---
    Button save = (Button)
            getActivity().findViewById(R.id.saveButton);


    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {




            try{
            Float conductivity = Float.parseFloat(conductivity_field.getText().toString());

                if (conductivity > 0.F && conductivity < 1000.F) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The value is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    //conductivity_field.setText(R.string.conductivity_field);//set text of the edittext back to the hint
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong value for float", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }


        }catch(Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error converting values. Please enter correct value.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

So i'm trying to display these errors but when i click it , it ignores the if condition and catches the exception and displays "error converting values msg...."

is there any other way?

Comment: You can check the length of EditText  if length is equal to 0 or length is greater then 1000

Comment: What the value did you enter to edittext?

Comment: @VasilyKabunov i just entered, 10, 23.2 900 all but it just skips everytime even if the value is between the range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace you code by this code ->

```
EditText conductivity_field;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_fragment,container, false);
        conductivity_field = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.conductivity_value);

        int field = getArguments().getInt("field");

        //Modify label
        // TextView fieldLabel = (TextView)v.findViewById(field);
        //fieldLabel.setText(MainActivity.pageNames[field]);

        return v;


    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        //---Button view---
        Button save = (Button)
                getActivity().findViewById(R.id.saveButton);


        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try{
                    Float conductivity = Float.parseFloat(conductivity_field.getText().toString());

                    if (conductivity > 0.F && conductivity < 1000.F) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The value is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {

                        //conductivity_field.setText(R.string.conductivity_field);//set text of the edittext back to the hint
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong value for float , BITCH", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error converting values. Please enter correct value.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: can u also help me with another issue?? its a minor one

Comment: share your problem .

Comment: when i click the button and the value is incorrect, i have to set the android:text of the edittext back to its hint text. how can i do that??

Comment: use this with your `EditText`  

`android:inputType="numberDecimal"  
android:hint="Enter your number .." `

you will never get any error data

Comment: its the requirement of my project hehe thats why im pushing for it :D

basically, the android hint is set as 0.-1000 now when button clicks, the text in the field should be set back to its hint text.

Comment: Do you mean something like this ? 

when click on button you can do this. Before do this you need to keep the data before clear the setText();

`editText.setHint(editText.getText());
 editText.setText("");`

Comment: exactly like that thanx heaps

Answer (score 1):

```
Button save;
Edittext conductivity_field;     

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field_fragment, container, false);
            initViews(view);
            return view;
}     

public void initViews(View v) {
                conductivity_field = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.conductivity_value);
                save= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

                save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        try {
                            Float conductivity = Float.parseFloat(edittext.getText().toString());

                            if (conductivity > 0f && conductivity < 1000f) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The value is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {

                                //conductivity_field.setText(R.string.conductivity_field);//set text of the edittext back to the hint
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wrong value for float", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error converting values. Please enter correct value.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

   }
```

Comment: i have put my code for whole java file. can u check that and tell me where to initialize edit text....

Comment: it worked too, :) but the up one was what i needed :D thank u

Answer (score 0):

initialize the edittext to onCreateView method of fragment and use the reference of edittext to get the entered value,
what you are doing, initializing a new edittext named as conductivity_field and by default its value is blank so you are getting exception while parsing edittext value to float